# C# have code in solution compiling and versioned but not in output assembly

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs

We have some dynamic C# code that is compiled and executed at runtime.
Both for versioning (TFS) as well as to find possible syntax errors, intellisense, etc. we have the code in our main solution.

This code should not be in the generated assembly though since it might contain data that is not to be distributed.

Is there any way to get the desired behavior of having it in each compile and also not having it in the generated output?

We do have a TFS-based build system, though it would be good to also have this feature for local compiles on each developer's machine.

Comment: Any chance you could just put it in a separate project? That's what I'd normally do. Without knowing more about what you're doing with it, it's slightly tricky to be more concrete than that.

Comment: Yes, I thought about that too, and then deleting the file e. g. in a post build event. Or obfuscating the generated file. Both are ok but not great solutions.

Comment: I'm not sure what file you mean - I think there's a lot of context we don't have at this point. It would be helpful if you could make the question more concrete, showing what files you have and what you want to do with them when.

Comment: With file I mean the generated assembly (off the sources I talked about). Have the assembly get built to get the feedback on the build and on possible compile errors, then delete it in order not to deploy it to customers.

Comment: If it's in an entirely separate project (in the same way as test projects etc), you'd have to work *to* deploy it... you shouldn't need to manually clean up anything.